# problems running kivy on android

Tags: android, kivy

I have a problem when I run my kivy app on android and it doesn't work on all mobile phones, I have a moto g9(play) and the app doesn't work for me and I've tried it on a moto g41 and it works without problems. Has this happened to anyone? I have already searched with google and I can't find an answer anywhere

MOTO g9(play):

2GHz Snapdragon 662 Octa-Core processor with 4GB of RAM.
64GB internal memory.
OS: Android 11

MOTO g41:

Processor: Mediatek Helio G85 2GHz
RAM: 4GB
Storage: 128GB
OS: Android 11(updated to 12)

The logcat does not throw me any errors on any mobile.

I tried making the app without any function, only with the structure of the .kv file and the same thing happens.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You aren't providing any details (a) what does your app do (b) the OS versions on each device (even if the same you should mention it) and (c) and any differences in the logcat between the two devices.

Comment: Now I edit it and add more information. the logcat does not throw me any error on any mobile

Comment: And running the same app on a Android 11 emulator vs Android 12 emulator is the same or different?

Comment: I tried on an android 9 and it works, it is not a problem of the android version